# Alamofire Get Request and JSON Response

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to use the [Yoda API](https://www.mashape.com/ismaelc/yoda-speak) and send a request using the [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) Swift framework. I know that the API is correctly working, as I have tested the endpoint with my Mashape API key multiple times. I can also see that the requests are being sent (homepage of Mashape under my application). However my JSON response is always `nil`.

```
func handleRequest(words:String){
        var saying = words.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "+");
        saying = "?sentence=" + saying;
        let url = NSURL(string: (baseURL+saying));
        println(url);
        var response:String;
        Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = additionalHeaders;
        Alamofire.request(.GET, url!).responseJSON { (_, _, JSON, _) in
            println(JSON);

        }
    }
```

The **words** string can be "This is my first sentence" and it will automatically replace the spaces with "+" as per the API spec. **Please Ignore** the multiple `println` statements, they are just for debugging.

This is just proof of concept code, its purposely not doing much error checking and isn't pretty for that reason. If you have any suggestions I would appreciate them.

Comment: It'll be much easier to help you out if you can include the actual URL being used.

Comment: Sure, an example that would work as passed into the `url` constant
https://yoda.p.mashape.com/yoda?sentence=You+will+learn+how+to+speak+like+me+someday.++Oh+wait.

Comment: That last closure argument that you're currently ignoring with `_` is an `NSError` that you can check to see why `JSON` might be `nil`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason it's an issue I've too with the Alamofire request for JSON. It is the way I handle the JSON requests using Alamofire :

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, urlTo, parameters: nil, encoding: .URL).responseString(completionHandler: {
        (request: NSURLRequest, response: NSHTTPURLResponse?, responseBody: String?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        // Convert the response to NSData to handle with SwiftyJSON
        if let data = (responseBody as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            let json = JSON(data: data)
            println(json)
        }
})
```

I strongly recommend you using [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) to manage the JSON in a better and easy way, it's up to you.

I hope this help you.

Comment: Your code worked, with the exception that Xcode as yelling at the cast in the if condition.

`if let data = (responseBody as! NSString)`

Notice **as!** instead of **as**

Comment: It's all good. I greatly appreciate the response, saved me a great headache!

Comment: I have a little confusion to provide the parameters in get request for almofire

Answer (score 6):

Alamofire request have several method for handle response. Try to handle data response and convert it to String. Confirm that response JSON is normal.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url!).response { (_, _, data, error) in
    let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    println(str)
    println(error)
}
```

Also checkout error while parsing JSON data.

Comment: Would better to use String(data: data,encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) instead of NSString object